# Michael Line is not Lindelöf

Tags: general-topology, lindelof-spaces

As we know, the Michael line is not Lindelöf. The links

- [https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/#:~:text=Result%202-,To%20see%20that,-is%20not%20Lindelof](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/#:%7E:text=Result%202-,To%20see%20that,-is%20not%20Lindelof)

and

- [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471133/the-michael-line-is-not-lindel%c3%b6f#:~:text=HINT%3A%20Find%20an%20uncountable%20closed%20discrete%20subset%20of%20the%20Michael%20line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471133/the-michael-line-is-not-lindel%c3%b6f#:%7E:text=HINT%3A%20Find%20an%20uncountable%20closed%20discrete%20subset%20of%20the%20Michael%20line)

tell us that if we can find an uncountable, closed, and discrete subset of the Michael line, then the Michael line is not Lindelöf. But *why* is this the case? What is it about finding a subset like this that makes the Michael line not Lindelöf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a topological space $(X,\tau)$ and an uncountable closed discrete set $C\subseteq X$, then we can consider the following open cover of $X$: $$\{\{x\} \mid x \in C\} \cup \{X\setminus C\}.$$
If $X$ were Lindelöf, then there would be a countable subcover, but such a subcover, being countable, cannot cover $C$, hence the above cover doesn't have any countable subcover and $X$ is not Lindelöf.

Answer (score 3):

[Every closed subspace of a Lindelöf space is also a Lindelöf space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4080221/a-closed-subset-of-a-lindel%c3%b6f-space-is-lindel%c3%b6f). But an uncountable discrete space is not Lindlöf.